# Why can a abstract class be instance in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The following code is from the project https://github.com/android/sunflower

In my mind, a abstract class can't be instanced, `AppDatabase` is a abstract class  in Code A.

Why can Code B instance the abstract class `AppDatabase`.

**Code A**

```
...
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun gardenPlantingDao(): GardenPlantingDao
    abstract fun plantDao(): PlantDao

    companion object {

        // For Singleton instantiation
        @Volatile private var instance: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            return instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also { instance = it }
            }
        }

    ...
}
```

**Code B**

```
fun provideAppDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): AppDatabase {
     return AppDatabase.getInstance(context)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't create instance of an abstract class.

Expression `buildDatabase(context)` actually returns instance of a class that is inherited from `AppDatabase`.

I suppose, this class is generated by annotation processor in the build time.

Comment: Yes and furthermore the companion object is not even needed and incorrect here.

Answer (score 2):

@Dima Rostapira is right, the abstract class is not really instantiated, but another class which extends from Appdatabase is generated by room. Furthermore, I would like to add, that the way you provide your db is not correct, but can be corrected the following:

```
@Database(entities = [YourEntityClass::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun plantDao(): PlantDao

    companion object {
       const val DATABASE_NAME = "app_database"
    }
}


@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DatabaseModule {

   @Provides
   @Singleton
   fun provideAppDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): AppDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(
        context,
        AppDatabase::class.java,
        AppDatabase.DATABASE_NAME
).fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()
}
```